# How to ignore English mistakes in Eclipse comments

Tags: eclipse, comments, spell-checking

I need to make Eclipse stop checking for English mistakes in my comments. It's annoying to see things underlined in red, and we use many "private" names during a project, so this feature is not useful to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Preferences and search for *spell* in the search field at the top. There you'll find the option to disable spell checking.

[image]